# How to position a HTML5 dialog element in the page?

Tags: html

Is there a simple way to show these two (or more) dialogs (HTML TAG) in different position in the screen? The idea is that each dialog would load different iFrames.

```
<html>

<body>
    <dialog open id="first">
        <iframe
            src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik">
        </iframe>
    </dialog>

    <dialog open id="second">
        <iframe
            src="https://www.google.com">
        </iframe>
    </dialog>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems like you can use CSS as though you were positioning a `display: absolute` element (`top`, etc.). (For example: `top: -10px` would move it up 10px.) You can also override `margin` and related if you need even more control.